# Possible for variable to cancel in a product of multivariate rational expressions?

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

Let $f,g,p_i,q_i$ be polynomials over some field with $\gcd(p_i,q_i)=1$ and $q_i$ are not constants for $i=1,2$. Assume that one or more of $p_i$ or $q_i$ has a term containing a variable $x$ not present in $f$ or $g$, does the simplified product

$$(f+\frac{p_1}{q_1})(g+\frac{p_2}{q_2})$$

necessarily contain the variable $x$?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you require $p_1$ to be coprime to $q_2$?

Comment: No, I don't require anything more.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you implicitly considering polynomials with coefficients in a field?

Comment: Yes, I added that assumption there. If it's not over an integral domain, then it would be very easy to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: Take $q_1 = 1$, $p_1 = -f$ (and $p_2 = x$, say) - then the product is $0$. Presumably you want to exclude this case?

Comment: OK, so you just added the constraint that the $q_i$ are not constant. Normally I'd be grumpy about people changing questions after I'd answered them, but this time you've made it more interesting so I don't mind :)

Comment: Sorry Ben. I'll also edit the part of the question that seems to indicate this should be easy, since it seems like it's not. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\[\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{1+x}\right) = 1\]

Comment: I suppose you're now going to tell me that the $p_i$ can't be constant either :P

Comment: Damn it. This actually causes a problem in my case, so I'll accept it. :)

Comment: We can also now multiple the left-hand side with $y^2$ and then $p$ isn't constant either.

Comment: The page somehow failed to load your answer while I was typing mine up - anyways, +1. Here's a counterexample with none of the polynomials constant: $f=g=y, p_1=x−1, q_1=x, p_2=(1−y−y^2)x+y, q_2=xy+x−1$

Comment: @zcn: no harm in having two answers :)